# How to upload a photo to user's wall using Facebook Javascript API (2014)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

First of all, I know there are plenty of questions and answers about the same topic, but none of them seem to work for me... This might be because many of them are from 2011 or 2012, and the FB API could have changed and the methods could be outdated... Let me briefly summarize my problem:

**What I want to do?**

Upload a PNG or JPEG photo stored in a server to the user's wall.

**How do I want to do so?**

Using Facebook's Javascript API, presumably by calling "FB.api()". I've been dealing with "FB.ui()" a bit and I've managed to successfully upload some things, but I don't know if it's possible to upload a simple photo to the user's wall using the "ui()" method (hope so!).

**What am I doing now?**

Here is the code I'm running now:

```
CocoonJS.Social.Facebook.api('/me/photos', 'post', 
    {
        message:'Luke: I am your Guinness',
        access_token: game.data.access_token, 
        url:'http://www.theagencyonline.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Darth-Vader-Guinness.gif'        
    }, function(response){
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
            } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
            }
});
```

**What am I getting?**

Strangely, after calling this function, the alert with the "Post ID" pops-up with a large number (the actual post ID, I guess). However, nothing is published in the wall. I'm using my own account to test it and I'm unable to see the post published.

**Messy things that could be related with the problem (or not):**

- Legends tell about user's "access token": some believe it is the key parameter, some don't even use it.
- Some people believe that uploading a photo can't be done through "/me/photos", but through "/{user_id}/photos".
- My FB application is still in sandbox mode (not made public).

And, finally, a simple question that could solve the whole thing... I've been able to publish things through "FB.ui()" instead of "FB.api()", but I can't find a way to publish photos through "ui()": do you know if it's possible? If so, how can be done?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort! :)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos/#publish specify that you should use encoded curly brackets to wrap your `url` paramenter content:

```
url=%7Bimage-url%7D
```

Strange that you get a `photo_id` returned. What happens if you query this `photo_id`?

Also, check what the default publishing settings of your app are. Quote from FB for the `privacy` field:

> If not supplied, this defaults to the privacy level granted to the app
>   in the Login Dialog. This field cannot be used to set a more open
>   privacy setting than the one granted.

Comment: Hi Tobi! Adding these encoded brackets to the URL returns an error, not even a "Post ID"... The error, however, is always "undefined", so I have no clue what can be happening... I simply changed my URL for "url:'%7Bhttp://www.theagencyonline.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Darth-Vader-Guinness.gif%7D'", but nothing...

Comment: Hmmm, ok... What about the `privacy` field?

Comment: I'm new to the FB API and I don't know exactly how to retrieve the `privacy` field... I've called `FB.api(response.id, 'get', function(response2){ alert('Post: '+response2.id+", "+response2.privacy); } });` with the returned `post_id` (which is `response.id`) and, though the alert retrieves the expected ID correctly, `response2.privacy` returns `undefined`... How could I check it?

Comment: Just take the `post_id` and put it in the Graph Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer I updated my answer with another hint.

Comment: I've tried calling `v2.0/10203987693281115` from Graph Explorer and got a GraphMethodException `Unsupported get request`... Does it mean that the post isn't actually made (so it's unable to get it), or am I doing something wrong? About my app's privacy configuration, the "Approved items" on the "Status & Review" app's page shows "email", "publich profile" and "user_friends"... I guess the one I need to publish is the second one, so it seems it's already granted...

Comment: You need the `publish_actions` permission to post photos for the User, and `user_photos` to be able to request them. It only works for your User if he's the admin of the app without having gathered the explicit permissions.

Comment: I'm trying to login with the extended permissions but I'm unable to retrieve the "grantedScopes" parameter to see whether the user actually granted them (I'm getting "undefined", which seems to be a trending value in FB API)... I'm calling `CocoonJS.Social.Facebook.login(function(response) { console.log("GRANTED: "+response.authResponse.grantedScopes); }, { scope: 'publish_actions', return_scopes: true });`, which seems to be the right way of doing so... Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried post the photo through the Graph Explorer and it got posted well! However, when trying from within my app, it doesn't work (though it returns the ID)... I think I'm actually requesting the "publish_actions" permission (the app asked me for them), so it seems as if I'm already doing all I have to...